# python - pygtk delete all the images in Table

Tags: python, image, replace, pygtk

I have a Table with images like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.tableau_img = gtk.Table(rows=3, columns=6, homogeneous=False)
    self.box.add(self.tableau_img)
    ligne = 0
    colonne = 0
    for i in range(1,20):         # to place 20 images in 6 colums, 3 rows
        self.image = gtk.Image()
        self.image.set_from_file("file.jpg")
        if i != 1 and i != 9 and i != 17:
           ligne = ligne + 1
        if i == 7:
           colonne = 1
           ligne = 0
        if i == 14:
           colonne = 2
           ligne = 0
        self.tableau_img.attach(self.image, ligne, ligne+1, colonne, colonne+1, xpadding=0, ypadding=5)
```

I would like to replace images in another "def", but I need to delete images before:

```
def delete_img(self, x, y):
    ligne = 0
    colonne = 0
    for i in range(1,20):
       if i != 1 and i != 9 and i != 17:
          ligne = ligne + 1
       if i == 7:
          colonne = 1
          ligne = 0
       if i == 14:
          colonne = 2
          ligne = 0
       #self.tableau_img.remove(self.image, ligne, ligne+1, colonne, colonne+1) # don't work
       #self.tableau_img.remove(self.image) # only the last one is deleted
```

My problem: how to delete all the images in the table to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
self.img = []
for i in range(1,20):
   self.image = gtk.Image()
self.image.set_from_file("img_8Info_Midi_.jpg")
if i != 1 and i != 9 and i != 17:
   ligne = ligne + 1
if i == 7:
   colonne = 1
   ligne = 0
if i == 14:
   colonne = 2
   ligne = 0
self.tableau_img.attach(self.image,          ligne, ligne+1, colonne, colonne+1, xpadding=0, ypadding=5)
self.img.append(self.image)
```

And the deletion:

```
for image in self.img:     
    self.tableau_img.remove(image)
```